# saving each item while in loop vb.net

Tags: datagridview, each

i need to make my storedprocedure update as as the messabox reads each item of a datagridview. it only save the last record that messagebox read.   need help:(

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                Dim strunitprice As String = CDbl(row.Cells(7).FormattedValue) + Val(CDbl(TXTNET.Text))

                'opening the connection
                x = MessageBox.Show(CDbl(row.Cells(7).FormattedValue) + Val(CDbl(TXTNET.Text)))
                If x = DialogResult.OK Then
                    Label27.Text = CDbl(row.Cells(7).FormattedValue) + Val(CDbl(TXTNET.Text))
                End If

Dim dr5 As SqlDataReader
        Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
        connectme.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * from quotation", connectme)
        dr5 = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

        While dr5.Read()
            connectme1.Close()

            Dim c As New SqlCommand("updatequotation", connectme1)
            Dim Adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(c)
            c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            c.Parameters.Add("@Customer_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =   txtclientname.Text
            c.Parameters.Add("@Date_Today", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label7.Text
            c.Parameters.Add("@Net_Income", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TXTNET.Text
            c.Parameters.Add("@Unit_Price", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label27.Text
            connectme1.Open()
            c.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connectme1.Close()
        End While
        dr5.Close()
        connectme.Close()


            Next row
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you closing connection and then creating command out of it. Remove the connection.close() from while loop and run the code again. It should work.